# Is reading "What if?" by Randall Munroe on kindle satisfactory?

Tags: kindle

I would like to buy the xkcd Book "What if?" for my kindle. But since graphical elements are important to get the complete dose of fun and nerdgasms, I would like to hear from someone who bought it whether the kindle version is good or not.

Amazon writes on the books page that the book is "optimized for larger screens" but doesn't specify how disadvantageous a kindle is in comparison to a 'real' book.

Comment: I'm afraid this question doesn't really fit the site guidelines (http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which state: "The main focus is on the processes involved in publishing and/or consuming ebooks (and related tools), rather than on the content of ebooks."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on your requirement for font sizes.

Just download the free sample (can even be done from your Kindle device) and flip pages until you arrive at the first pictures. For me they are quite small, but large enough to read the text. You can also select the pictures to view them full screen.

Another way of reading this is not buying it at all, but converting the web pages. This can be done for example using the [grabmybooks](http://www.grabmybooks.com) browser extension. Note that it relies on [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for the conversion from `.epub` to `.mobi`. The result looks similar to the book for me.

I may add that the latter way did not always work well. In the past I had problems with pictures missing or being black. Now it works, but I cannot say if this is due to bugfixes in grabmybooks or Calibre or if xkcd used another image format (or version) in the older articles.

Comment: Great Answer! I didn't know you could view the free sample on the kindle as well.
After doing this my conclusion is, that its quite good on my kindle. The only disappointment is, that the full screen pictures a in a low resolution so that they appear a bit blurred.